# How to auto run JavaScript on Chrome startup/new tab creation?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Is there a possibility to set your Chrome browser to run a JavaScript snippet upon startup or with every new tab creation?

As an example, I create a new snippet in the Dev Tools > Sources > Snippets:

[image: One]

[image: Two]

Once you press CTRL + ENTER to run the script, you'll see this:

[image: Three]

Cool! Problem is, this message will disappear upon refreshing or closing and reopening Chrome. So to mitigate having to create and run that simple script every time, I'd like a way to have it saved and ran every time Chrome is run and (ideally) whenever a new tab is created.

Only way I can think to do this would be to create a Chrome Extension, but wondering if there's a way to do this locally/without having to go through the Chrome Store.

Comment: https://rigorousthemes.com/blog/best-tampermonkey-alternatives/

Comment: So no way to do this WITHOUT using the Chrome Store/Extensions?

Comment: No, no way to EXTEND Chrome features/behaviours without an extension

Comment: @Salketer possible to make and “install” your own extension without having to do it through the chrome store? Like creating a JS file and loading it into the extensions folder of chrome in Program Files, or something like that??

Comment: Yes totally, https://superuser.com/questions/247651/how-does-one-install-an-extension-for-chrome-browser-from-the-local-file-system